# How to use GPT-4 in Q&A

Tags: weaviate

Request to Weaviate Q&A service:

```
$weaviate = new Weaviate('http://weaviate:8080/v1/', '');
    $res = $weaviate->graphql()->get('{
Get {
  '.self::$weaviateClass.' (
    ask: {
      question: "'.$request->q.'",
      properties: ["content"]
    },
    limit: 1
  ) {
    title
    _additional {
      answer {
        hasAnswer
        property
        result
        startPosition
        endPosition
      }
    }
  }
}
  }');

dd($res);
```

How can I use GPT-4-32k or GPT-4 ?
Cant find any docs or examples for configuration.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I use GPT-4-32k or GPT-4 ? Cant find any docs or examples for configuration.

https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/modules/reader-generator-modules/generative-openai gives the following example:

```
{
  Get {
    Article(
      nearText: {
        concepts: ["Italian food"]
      }
      limit: 1
    ) {
      title
      summary
      _additional {
        generate(
          singleResult: {
            prompt: """
              Describe the following as a Facebook Ad: {summary}
            """
          }
        ) {
          singleResult
          error
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that since 2023-11-06, GPT-4 can do [RAQ-QA](https://openai.com/blog/new-models-and-developer-products-announced-at-devday).